# Can we use images in CSS background in Google AMP?

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Can we use images in CSS background in Google AMP?

```
<pre>

    <div style="background-image: url(assets/img/business1.jpg);></div>


</pre>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do like this :

**CSS on head section**

```
<style amp-custom>
    .img-background { background-image: url(assets/img/business1.jpg); }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<pre>
<div class="img-background"></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: How to display background image for dynamic loop content. eg display posts

Comment: Yes, you can achieve. In loop you have to create unique class and css in head section for same class

Comment: I am trying to use this method and I want the image to fill the width of the screen and then have the height be calculated so the aspect ratio is 16 x 9, as can be easily done with an amp-image.  How do I get the div the right size?  Should I use an amp-img, and then position my text on top using 'position:absolute'?

Answer (score 3):

AMP does not support inline styles (like your example), but you could add a `background-image` by implementing styles the proper way in a `<style amp-custom>` tag in the `<head>`.

Read more here: [Supported CSS - AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can also mimic the behavior of a background image by creating a container with `position: relative` that wraps the amp-img and the content and make the content `position: absolute` and have it cover the dimensions of the amp-img like so:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: '1200px';
  height: '700px';
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <amp-img
    src="https://www.variety.org.au/sa/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/placeholder.png"
    width="1200px"
    height="700px"
    layout="responsive"></amp-img>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>My Content </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```